# How does 9/11 compare with the fire in the Reichstag, Berlin – in terms of consequences?

Tags: united-states, germany, history, nazism

Is there a similarity between 9/11 and the [USA PATRIOT act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriot_Act) and the [Reichstag Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_fire) in 1933, after Hitler used democracy to seize absolute power (although 67% didn't vote for him)?

After 9/11 the Patriot act came into being. It was said the citizens of the U.S.A. were accepting of their liberties being lessened as this was for their own good: protection against the enemy, the Muslims.

This seems similar to what was done in the Nazi era: after the Reichstag was completely destroyed by a fire, the Nazis blamed a Dutchman, Marinus van der Lubbe, an alleged communist, for the fire. This was followed by an emergency decree which constrained the people's liberty, similarly to what happened after the Patriot Act was issued.

In how far are they similar. In howfar not?

Comment: I would like to see where this question stands on the Truther bit.  Because 2 things are for sure:  the Reichstag was a false flag op.  And lots of people believe 9/11 was so that is a massive, massive, point of comparison, depending on where one stands on Truthers.  As as M. Moore goes, though I could not find his position on Truthers, Slate has a nice [op ed](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2004/06/the-lies-of-michael-moore.html) on this documentary.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica At least someone who agrees with me!? What's the Truther bit?

Comment: I find it odd you wouldn't know.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9/11_Truth_movement

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Non sono omnisapiente! Thanx!

Comment: OK, correction on my end.  Reichstag events were manipulated by the Nazis and *possibly* a false flag.  But it certainly wasn't an act carried it out under the circumstances claimed and people often label it as false flag.  So, where does that leave your question wrt its stance on 9/11 actual perpetrators?  Bin Laden and the boys?  Or something falsely attributed/facilitated by the US govt?

Comment: I find it very hard to believe you wouldn't know what truthers are but want to argue about WTC 7's part in the false flag theory, as you did with Tim's answer.  -1, this question is, IMHO, asked in bad faith.

Comment: Ahm: The linked Q is was posted by 'you' *and* into the same direction?  Instead of just linking to that, perhaps explain what would be different between those? If you do not do that, I am inclined to vote for dupe closure quite soon?

Comment: @LаngLаngС So I made a duplicate of my own question. I just wanted to show that Michael Moore and I had the same thought. But if you want to close it, no problem.

Comment: @LangLangC as far as I'm aware, there is no rule prohibiting duplicates on *different* SE sites...

Comment: @DescheleSchilder As was already mentioned, right now this question looks suspiciosly like an attempt at soapboxing; besides that, "how far is a comparison justified" seems like an invitation for a discussion. I'd advise you to 1) reframe the question to make it look less as an invitation for a discussion; 2) explain more in-depth how you view the two events in question (and why are you thinking that legislation they resulted in is similar) instead of just linking to wiki, to demonstrate that you are asking in good faith. For now - vtc.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov Soapboxing? That's the last thing I want to do! As you say "this question looks ", and looks can deceive. I just think that both actions served the same goal, i..e.. giving the powers that are (were) even more power. And I totally agree with Michael Moore in his documentary, where he put some modern comment (about 9/11) on old images of the Reichstag event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mark Twain once quipped: "History doesn't repeat itself, but it rhymes." There are obvious parallels between the Reichstag fire and the 9/11 attacks — as well as between the resulting [Reichstag Fire Decree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_Fire_Decree) and the Patriot Act — but there are obvious differences as well:

- The Reichstag Fire was ostensibly the act of a 'lone wolf' that the Nazi Party built into a broad communist conspiracy; the 9/11 attacks were actually committed by an organized conspiracy (i.e., the people who undertook the attacks were recruited, funded, and organized by Al-Qaeda, operating in secret to do maximal damage).
- The Nazi Party used the Fire as a pretext to secure domestic political control; The W Bush administration mainly used 9/11 as a pretext to change *foreign* policy (uprooting international conventions, engaging in unilateral 'preemptive' war, and generally pulling the US away from the UN and other international constraints).

Historically speaking, the 1933 events are best seen as the beginnings of a *coup d'état* in which the Nazi Party had the explicit goal of creating a regime change that would leave them in perpetual power. The 2001 events, by contrast, appear more as a shift towards militarism within the existing regime, arguably because the GOP felt that renewing America's military posture — the posture that had made the USA preeminent from WWII through the end of the Cold War — would serve them well at the polls. W Bush (or more accurately, people in his administration, such as Cheney) had the *opening* to try and create regime change in 2007: protracted foreign wars, a flailing economy, domestic strife; all time-tested justifications for exerting authoritarian control. Instead, the GOP allowed the democratic process to play out, and stepped down from power when they lost.

Of course, the GOP 'stepping down' was perceived as failure by the more Rightist components of the party, and inflamed a nationalist movement that led to Trumpism. We can expect 2020 to rhyme more soundly with 1933 (even if Trumpists have to conjure an 'October Surprise' domestic attack out of whole cloth, to boost their fear-mongering campaign). Hopefully this bit of historical doggerel will have a decidedly different outcome.

Comment: **Hopefully this bit of historical doggerel will have a decidedly different outcome.** I hope so too. Is it possible that a dictatorship gets a grip on the U.S.A.? Can constitutional laws prevent this?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder: As I've said before, government is built on *institutions*, not *laws*, meaning that governments only function well when there is a near-universal tacit 'understanding' about the rules the government operates under. Any government (and democratic governments in particular) are vulnerable to someone willing to subvert and abuse those tacit understandings, for pretty much the same reason that any individual can get taken in by a grift or scam. We don't expect sneaky rule-breakers, and don't adjust quickly or well when we're confronted by one.

Comment: The Reichstag-fire was in terms of 911 conspiracy explanations most probably a MIHOP event. Van der Lubbe just a scape goat, brought to the scene when it was already aflame. (If you don't want to build your argument on that specific historical point,  in either way, perhaps leave that still slightly controversial point slightly open? But you may as well trust me on that, or ask on HistorySE for more details on it… ;) Reliance on 'sole arsonist' isn't necessary here imo anyway. A crisis is a chance. The outcome is what matters more.)

Comment: @DescheleSchilder: A constitution is nothing except a document that spells out some basic institutions. If someone refuses to respect the institutions, the document isn't worth the paper it's printed on. But on the other hand, the institutions spelled out in the US constitution are deeply embedded in US political culture. Someone might pull the wool over our eyes for a while, but uprooting the institutional norms *entirely* would be difficult. My estimation is that Trump would need much more support than he actually has to pull that rabbit out of the hat. Not that he might not try...

Comment: @LаngLаngС: Your last point is where I'm at as well. How an event is *used* demonstrates the character and nature of the movement, regardless of the factual details of the event itself.  But I can throw in the word 'ostensibly' to loosen it up a little, if you like.

Comment: An impressively elegant solution to that problem. Kudos. However, the second bullet, things like '*Homeland* Security' are not just "foreign policy"? That event was used to 'change everything'. An exaggeration, if taken literally, but 'external' as well as 'internal' outlook would be a fit? The threat model is of course still 'externalised' in direction, but the obvious practical implications are also internal ('traitors, infiltrators, sleepers' etc).

Comment: Wasn't a coupe détat already committed in 1923 by Hitler and friends?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder: the 1923 Beer Hall Putsch was an abortive attempt to take over Munich by force. I think they anticipated it would inspire a popular uprising that didn't happen. Hitler served time, reorganized, got elected to office, and then began a new coup from within the government. The only virtue evil people share is persistence...

Answer (score 4):

It's not.  The Reichstag event was either a false flag operation or the act of one person, willfully misrepresented as a Communist plot.  In any case, we know the Nazi penchant for false flag operations, such as [pretending Poland had attacked them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleiwitz_incident).

- There is no doubt the Nazis were not being honest about the actual danger to their state.

The WTC attack was an actual attack, with large loss of life, by Al-Quaeda, who explicitly claimed responsibility.

- The US government had ample justifications to take measures of some sort, although opinions about the measures that ended up being taken may differ.  I am not arguing on the merits of what the Bush administration did.

Now, we could debate Patriot Act vs Nazi power grab, if this question really was about the legal measures taken by both governments, rather than casting doubt on the circumstances of the WTC attack by associating it with a known [false flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag#Reichstag_fire) incident or at least often perceived as such.

There is a whole [industry of conspiracy theorists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9/11_conspiracy_theories) who claim that the WTC attack was not, in fact, an actual external attack, but rather somehow organized by shadowy actors in the US government or at least US-based.  Like the Nazis, those conspirators would then be able to manipulate legislation having fooled the gullible into supporting them.

That is the comparison that is being made in this question:  equating a possible false flag, and certainly misrepresented, Reichstag to a claimed false flag WTC.  The OP denies doing so, but then goes right into 9/11 Truther mode on Tim's answer:

> **OP:** What about the WTC building #7?

Conveniently, that [sentence can be looked right up](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00409/full).

Furthermore, when challenged about his position on the Truther movement, the OP innocently claims not to know anything about it, but then is able to recite usual Truther talking points perfectly.

While engaging very little on the actual political analysis of legislative changes in either answer.

Comment: **the OP innocently claims not to know anything about it, but then is able to recite usual Truther talking points perfectly** do you really think I'm that innocent? I'm very happy for your deserved rep. and totally disagree with your answer.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder  Well, easy enough to set the record straight, niet waar?  *"Do you believe that the WTC collapses of 3 buildings were ONLY the result of impacts by 2 airplanes? And the Pentagon was hit by another plane.  And that the Al-Quaeda perpetrators were NOT assisted by members of the US government or people close to it?  Not assisted means no intentional help - failure-to-recognize-threat is not assistance "*.  Yes or No?

Comment: E vero! 1)No 2)No 3)No E chiaro?

Comment: Wat een lap text over WTC gebouw zeven! Ik denk echter dat de schrijvers behoorlijk bevooroordeeld zijn. Maybe the conventionalistic point of view is the conspiracy theory. Non ti sembri?

Comment: Beter om te zeggen wat U echt bedoelt, eh?  Well, FWIW, I asked a question about [confirmed conspiracy theories on Stack History](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/55260/have-there-been-government-conspiracies-that-were-successful-for-over-25-years) and it was... not much.

Comment: Moore as far as I am concerned is a genius, like Ann Coulter or Rush Limbaugh, at making money.  He's found himself a nice niche selling scare stories about the "other side" to outraged fans.  I can't say I like Chomsky, whom I've read, much.  But he actually makes cogent arguments against the system in things like Manufacturing Consent, unlike the drivel the 3 above usually make money from.  Coulter was an especially hard read, I stopped after 50 pages.

Comment: Moore is indeed a genius in earning money. Why shouldn't he? He's funny too. What were the scare stories about after which he found himself in a nice niche (in Nice?)? Why were his fans outraged? Concerning Chomsky, I don't like "using cogent arguments against the system". No fun. Drivel is more fun. I think MM is making docu's which are a bit over the top but certainly thought-provoking, trying to make a change, and fun to watch.The other 2, I think I don't like their writings. I don't trust so-called intellectuals (which MM is certainly not) that much. Please fix the translation program.;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Differences in the events themselves**

There is some doubt about the origins of the Reichstagsbrand among historians & a false flag operation is a legitimate theory.

No reliable source attribute 9/11 to a false flag operation.

**Differences in impact**

The Reichstagsbrand was used to persecute political opponents - including elected representatives -, which was a central step in cementing Hitlers power.

From your [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_fire) link:

> After the decree was issued, the government instituted mass arrests of communists, including all of the Communist Party's parliamentary delegates. With their bitter rival communists gone and their seats empty, the Nazi Party went from having a plurality to a majority, thus enabling Hitler to consolidate his power.

Till Mai '33, [100,000 political opponents where arrested](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstagsbrand#Formale_Legalisierung_der_politischen_Verfolgung) and sent to concentration camps. Additionally, freedom of the press & freedom of speech [were](https://www.servat.unibe.ch/dns/rgbl_1933_i_83_vo_volk_staat-unterricht.pdf) severely restricted.

On the other hand, the Patriot Act did not substantially or directly impact the opposition. No democratic senators were sent to concentration camps.

**Differences in the laws**

The most impactful part of the [Verordnung des Reichspräsidentenzum Schutz von Volk und Staat](https://www.servat.unibe.ch/dns/rgbl_1933_i_83_vo_volk_staat-unterricht.pdf) is the annulation of paragraphs 114 (freedom of the person; nobody can be arrested without cause), 115 (protecting personal accommodations from unreasonable search), 117 (secrecy of correspondence), 118 (freedom of speech & freedom of the press), 123 (freedom of assembly), 124 (freedom of association) and 153 (right to property) of the constitution.

The (objectionable part of the) Partiot Act on the other hand focus mainly on surveillance & border security. If a comparison is to be made, the closest equivalent would be the annulation of §117 (secrecy of correspondence).

While there was a significant impact to the right to privacy, the Patriot Act does not really compare to the destruction of liberties in the aftermath of the Reichstagsbrand.

Comment: Comments deleted. This is not a place to debate 9/11 conspiracy theories.

Comment: I think you live in a fantasy world. You do not see what's really going on in the U.S.A. Just take a good look around you for yourself. I can't, because I'm not living in a country where there are fewer weapons per citizen than in Canada, while the murder rate is kinda higher!